# Как вывести результат работы процесса в терминал, зная его pid?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Есть скрипт, который запускает tcpdump. Как можно увидеть работу tcpdump в консоли в реальном времени, зная его pid? Сам скрипт запускается через cron.

Comment: а как именно он запускается? может он в терминал ничего не выводит?

Comment: Запускается при помощи os:  `os.system(tcpdump -i eth0)`.

Comment: это понятно, что с помощью os (операционной системы). Как именно?

Comment: Процесс висит в фоне. используя `ps ax` его видно, но непонятно, как вывести в консоль

Comment: все, что Вы пишете - очевидно и не несет никакой дополнительной информации. Ок, упрощу мой вопрос - как именно выглядит строка, которой в кроне запускается tcp dump?

Comment: В кроне запускается не tcpdump, а отдельный скрипт, в котором запускается tcpdump

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58550/110559

Comment: А ешё можно запускать внутри screen\tmux и аттачиться уже туда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, скрипт на Python и в нём написано не так

```
os.system(tcpdump -i eth0)
```

а вот так:

```
os.system("tcpdump -i eth0")
```

Знание pid при запуске этого скрипта Вам ничем не поможет. На самом деле, нужно сделать вот что:

1. Запустить *crontab -e*
2. Найти в таблице строку, которая запускает Ваш скрипт
3. В этой строке, скорее всего, стоит нечто вроде *> /dev/null*
4. Заменить на что-то типа *>> ~/log_tcpdump.txt*
5. Запустить *tail -f ~/log_tcpdump.txt*
6. Дождаться запуска скрипта по времени
7. Смотреть его выдачу

В комментариях приводится ссылка на рецепт типа :

tail -f /proc//fd/1

Ну... Это даст эффект на один раз. А при следующем запуске вашего скрипта у него будет другой PID и опять - всё с начала.

Comment: С pid процесса все легко. Если точно уверены, что процесс только один, тогда где то так `tai -f /proc/$(pidof tcpdump)/fd/1`. Если процессов может быть много - тогда нужно делать цикл. `for i in $(pidof tcpdump); do tailf /proc/$i/fd/1; done` (да, иногда лучше использовать `tailf`, а не `tailf -f`)

Comment: @KoVadim, `tailf` — команда устаревшая, будет удалена в 2017 г.